# Why does 5 :: Sum Integer work as literal?

Tags: haskell, literals

Why does `5 :: Sum Integer` work in the interpreter but given a

```
newtype NovoTipo a = NovoTipo a
```

`6 :: NovoTipo Integer` does not work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write numeric literals for any type which has a `Num` instance. `Sum` [has it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:3), while your newtype doesn't.

You can enable [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#generalised-derived-instances-for-newtypes) in ghci the following way:

```
:set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
```

Then you can write:

```
newtype NovoTipo a = NovoTipo a deriving (Num)
```

And then `6 :: NovoTipo Integer` is well-typed.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that w/o that extension, the instance can still be provided with manual (un)wrapping.